# procedure to move subdomain to different server

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, godaddy

I plan on having a subdomain, let's call it `foo.mysite.com`, forwarding to my site `www.mysite.com`. This is just for testing purposes.

Eventually I want to change my `foo.mysite.com` to point to another server. So I will be setting up another A record pointing to the new IP.

What I'm confused with is what do I do with the forwarded subdomain to mysite.com? I don't need to forward it anymore. So I think the procedure is:

1. Create new A record
2. Delete the subdomain
3. Create CNAME record with alias `foo` and host it points to as `foo.mysite.com`
4. Remove my 301 redirect in htaccess that had `foo.mysite.com` -> `www.mysite.com`

My hosting provider is GoDaddy. Assuming this procedure is correct then the final issue I have is the assignment of the A record. That can take some time. It is usually pretty quick but I'm building an app server that needs to be running immediately when I create the new A record.

How can I structure this better so I don't have an outage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CNAME for `foo` to an A record now. Point it to the same IP address as `www`. Then, when you are ready to go live with your web site on the new server, just change the A record. This has the additional benefit that you need not make any change on the *old* server.

Comment: I assume changing an A record happens immediately once it has been created? I assume I still need a 301 redirect until I move it over?

Comment: It should be a 302 redirect, not a 301. And the A record change happens as fast as you change it, subject to the TTL you specified.